# <where do I convert?> warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data

Tags: c++

The code below gives me following warning in line 174:

warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data

but I don't really understand why. I have vector `s` of `__int64`'s, but i'ts size is integer, `k` is also integer, so everything should be fine. Or maybe `k:s` works different than I thought?

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

__int64 count( vector<__int64> s, int n )
{
    vector<__int64> table(n+1,0);   // or: 0LL instead 0
    table[0] = 1;                   // or: 1LL instead 1
    for ( int k : s )    /* 174 */  // or:  for ( auto& k : s )`
        for(int j=k; j<=n; ++j)
            table[j] += table[j-k];
     return table[n];
}


int main()
{
// some code here
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for ( int k : s )` iterates over all the elements of `s`, and the template type of `s` is `__int64` so the type of `k` needs to be `__int64`

See: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html

Comment: Thank you for this link, this explains a lot :) I didn't know it was introduced in c++11 and didn't knew how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

change `for ( int k : s )` to `for ( auto& k : s )`, everything will be ok.

Comment: What do you use, that it works to you? If I change to auto, the similar error appears also in the next line, but this time it is __int64 to unsigned int, and this is why I got rid of auto :(

Comment: @Kusavil You need to use the same type for all the variables that are going to contain values from the vector, so `k` and `j` both need to be `__int64`

Comment: I thought that when I changed both `k` and `j`, then I got warning somewhere else, but it was because something other and now works fine. Thank you all :)