# initializing conversion from unsigned int64 to unsigned int

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, dynamic-arrays, data-loss

I've taken a look around and this error seems a little odd for me.
I've looked around at threads like [<where do I convert?> warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780507/where-do-i-convert-warning-c4244-initializing-conversion-from-int64), but my warning appears (to a noob like me) to be caused by something else.

I have a header file called "DArray.h", which defines and implements a template class for a dynamic array.
The internal array looks like this:

```
struct InternalArray
    {
        T element;
        bool isAssigned;
        void Assign(const T& in)
        {
            element = in;
            isAssigned = true;
        }
        InternalArray()
        {
            isAssigned = false;
        }
    };
    InternalArray* internalArray;
```

Where T is the template type for the whole class of DArray.

My warning appears whenever I need to resize that internal array, by making a temporary copy of it like this:

```
InternalArray* copyArray = new InternalArray[arraySize];
```

Where "arraySize" is an unsigned long long type.
To me it seems like it's only allowing me to create an array using an unsigned int type, and is automatically demoting 'arraySize' when I try to make copies like this.
I have also tried:

```
InternalArray* copyArray = new InternalArray[dynamic_cast<unsigned long long>(arraySize)];
```

However I'm told that __int64 is an invalid type for dynamic_cast.
I've also tried

```
InternalArray* copyArray = new InternalArray[static_cast<unsigned long long>(arraySize)];
```

However this doesn't effect the warning at all! I've also tried a C-style cast.
Gah I wish I wasn't so dumb. These warnings are non-fatal so far as I can tell, but also slightly worrying.
Could someone explain to me what exactly is happening when I'm calling this line?
If you have a solution it's totally welcome!

I should have made this clear: **I don't want 'arraySize' to be downgraded into an unsigned int, int, short or anything else. I want it to stay as an unsigned long long.**
Unless arraySize is not the item being downgraded. If not, what is? :/
Is it that you cannot create an array using an int64 type?

Comment: The argument to `operator new[]` must be `size_t`. If `size_t` is equivalent to `unsigned int`, you'll get this warning.

Comment: `static_cast<std::size_t>(arraySize)` is likely what you're looking for, but honestly `arraySize` should be a `std::size_t` to begin with (just as this entire menagerie would likely be better off just being `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Yes, using a size_t clears it up.
Why though? Is program not allowed to assign an array beyond this size?

Comment: `3.7.4p2 - [basic.stc.dynamic]` lists the library-provided prototypes for `operator new`, `operator new[]`, etc, using `size_t` as the magnitude parameter. `operator new` in `5.3.4 [expr.new]` is somewhat less restrictive, but doesn't change what the *standard library* provides. Likewise, "The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object." It makes little sense to allow a larger magnitude, since  the minimal addressable object is a single octet.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting an unsigned long long to an unsigned long long, which does very little to help resolve the warning.

You need to do this to cast it to the appropriate size integer

```
InternalArray* copyArray = new InternalArray[static_cast<size_t>(arraySize)];
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `static_cast<size_t>`?